# HTML, CSS, JQuery Slideshow using Array

Tags: jquery, html, css, arrays, slideshow

I'm trying to built my own slideshow following a tutorial. I don't want to use plug in or other easy way, I just want to build one by myself.
The problem is that the slideshow doesn't slide, when you reload the page there is the first image that after few seconds disappear. I can not find mistakes and I'm really getting crazy trying to find a solution.

```js
images = ["http://via.placeholder.com/500x700?text=one","http://via.placeholder.com/500x700?text=two","http://via.placeholder.com/500x700?text=three","http://via.placeholder.com/500x700?text=four"];
setInterval(forwardImage, 4000);

function currentImageKey() {
  i = jQuery.inArray($(".slideshow").attr("src"), images);
  return i;
};

function forwardImage() {
  currentImageKey();
  if (i < images.length - 1) {
    changeImage(i + 1);
  } else {
    changeImage(0);
  }
};

function changeImage(i) {
  $(".slideshow").stop().animate({
    opacity: 0,
  }, 200, function() {
    $(".slideshow").attr('src', images[i]);
    $(".holder img").load(function() {
      $(".slideshow").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
      }, 200)
    })
  })
};
```

```css
.slideshow {
  max-height:500px;
  max-width:700px;
}
.holder {
  height:500px;
  width:700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x700?text=one" height="500px" width="700px" class="slideshow"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the images to slide or just fade in and out? At the moment you have no sliding in there, just fading.

Comment: Would be great a nice fading effect. Thank you.

Comment: Funnily enough, editing your question to add some proper images that it will be able to find on the internet causes it to seemingly work, so I guess it's a problem with the path to your images in your application.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, the images are in my laptop, the path is: C:\Users\Marcello B*****\Documents\Folder's Name\Project's Name\pic1.jpg. When I wrote the path I tried the 'complete one' and the short with just pic1.jpg but in both the cases wont work. Which one should I use? Thank you.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason to use absolute (long) paths, you should go with relative paths, e.g. `/images/pic1.jpg`

Comment: Now I understand why didn't work, was just the wrong path. The problem now is that I tried both the way, long and short and the code doesn't work.
The long: 
images = ["C:\Users\Marcello *******\Documents\folder\another folder\pic1.jpg", ..............until pic4.jpg]
The short:
images = ["pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg","pic3.jpg","pic4.jpg"]

So the images are in the same folder of index.html where there are as well the .css and .js files.
How is the right path to write in the array to make work the code?
Thank you.